# Decode signature_message_fragment with utf-8

Tags: pyota

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 7: invalid start byte

from

```
RBPC9D9DCDEABCIIGHTCFDFA999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
```

using

print(str(transaction.signature_message_fragment.decode()))

Can anyone help me how to decode this message using Pyota?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your message is:

```
RB  H
PC  a
9D  l
9D  l
CD  o
EA   
BC  S
II  \xfc
GH  \xdf
TC  e
FD  r
FA  !
99
99
99
99
...
```

The two tryte pairs `II` and `GH` can't be decoded to UTF-8 characters.

```
>>> s = iota.TryteString(b'RBPC9D9DCDEABCIIGHTCFDFA')
>>> s.encode()
b'Hallo S\xfc\xdfer!'
```

This happens when you convert ASCII to trytes with the Javascript Library and then try to convert the trytes to UTF-8 with the Python Library.

Since UTF-8 is supposed to be backwards compatible with ASCII this shouldn't be a problem. But the [iota.lib.js-ASCII](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.lib.js/blob/develop/lib/utils/asciiToTrytes.js#L42) is [Extended ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII) which UTF-8 is not compatible with.

Since all the libraries should be compatible, I submitted an issue [here](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.lib.js/issues/243).

Comment: Hello Zaus, thanks for your answer! The original message is "Hallo Süßer!". Those are UTF-8 chars (c3bc and c39f). I created the message by just typing it into Trinity while sending a transaction.  Any ideas?

Comment: Seems like Trinity and Pyota use different methods. `s = iota.TryteString.from_unicode('Süß')'` and `s.decode()` works fine...